# Behaviour of $f(x)$ that satisfies $f'(x) \cos x \le f(x) \sin x$

Tags: functions, continuity

> Question:   Let $f(x),x\ge 0,$ be a non-negative continuous function. If $f'(x) \cos x\le f(x) \sin x, \forall x\ge 0,$  then $f(\frac{5 \pi}{3})=\dots$

**My Attempt :**  Define $f(x):[0,\infty)\to \mathbb [0,\infty)$ and choose $g(x)=f(x)\cos x$, now differentiating both sides we get $g'(x)=f'(x) \cos x-f(x)\sin x \le0\implies g(x)$ is monotonically decreasing. After this I was looking for the possible combinations of $f(x)$ that will do the job but I couldn't find any except $f(x)=0$ (indeed it satisfies the equation).

Now it looks like the question is to prove $f'(x) \cos x\le f(x) \sin x \implies f(x)\equiv0, \forall x \ge0.$

Assuming the case of equality, I solved the ODE but there came the existence of an arbitrary constant.

Thanks.

Comment: If $g:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ is monotonically decreasing and $g(a)=g(b)$ for some 0<a<b$, then $g$ must be constant on $[a,b]$. You can use the zeros of cosine for $g$ you defined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $g\left(\frac{3\pi}2\right)=g\left(\frac{5\pi}2\right)=0$ and $g$ is monotonically decreasing, $g\left(\frac{5\pi}3\right)=0$.

More generally, the same argument shows that the restriction of $g$ to $\left[\frac\pi2,\infty\right)$ is the null function.